# Shipping based on SKU - Magento CE 1.9.1.0

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, sku

I need a solution to a problem that I've been struggling with for some time now.

I *need some sort of shipping rule that changes price dependent on the END of an SKU*.

For example, if a `SKU` ended `xxxx-TICK` it would be charged at `£5.00`, where as a `SKU` ending in `xxxx-PHYS` would be charged at `£10.00`.

I've not come across any post or plugin that could solve this.

I'm open to all ideas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying your carrier model class's collectRates() method. Here, in this method you can check if the quote item has a product whose SKU ends with either 'TICK' or 'PHYS' and set $shippingPrice with the respective value.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();


foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $sku = $product->getSku();

    //your logic to compare the sku
    //for example
    if('sku ends with TICK'){
        $shippingPrice += 5; 
    }

    if('sku ends with PHYS'){
        $shippingPrice += 10; 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. If you have any doubts please feel free to ask me further.
Thanks.